# Undefine a constant in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

In C#, conditional compilation symbols can be undefined (removed) with:

```
#undef SYMBOL_1
// ...
#if SYMBOL_1
    ThisDoesNotRun();
#else
   ButThisDoesRun();
#endif
```

Visual Basic has something similar called "Constants":

```
#Const VB_SYMBOL_1 = True
' ...
#If VB_SYMBOL_1
    ThisWillRun()
#End If
#If Not VB_SYMBOL_1
   ButThisWillNot()
#End If
```

Does VB have functionality to undefine a constant, like `undef` in C#?

You can redefine the constant with `#Const VB_SYMBOL_1 = False`, but this is not the same thing.

Comment: #Const VB_SYMBOL_1 = Nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is from a comment to the question (thanks Hans). To undefine a preprocessor constant use:

```
#Const VB_SYMBOL_1 = Nothing
```